# Where is the value of deployment().name coming from in Azure Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

As part of our template files, we have a variable defined partially by [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-deployment#deployment) method's `deployment().name`, similar to this:

```json
"myVariable": "[concat(SOME_CUSTOM_STRING_HERE, deployment().name)]"
```

The variable is then used as the deployment label for our Classic Cloud Service resources which includes the build number.

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-12-01",
  "type": "deploymentSlots",
  "name": "staging",
  "properties": {
    "deploymentLabel": "[variables('myVariable')]",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Perhaps `deployment().name` can be set and not defined by Azure, but I haven't been able I haven't been able to find it.

However, the variable's value is different under Cloud Service Extended Support. This time the value is a long hash and the name of the Cloud Service resource, even thought the definition remains as shown above. The variable is used in a tag:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices",
  "name": "RESOURCE_NAME",
  "location": "[LOCATION]",
  "tags": {
    "DeploymentLabel": "[variables('myVariable')]",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

So did the value of `deployment().name` template function change for deployments of Extended Support version of cloud service? If not, can it be set and how?

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure Devops side, if you are running the deployment the task itself has the deployment name like deployment mode. if its not provided, automatically it gets generated

deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
deploymentName: 'deploymentname'

if its powershell then please check the link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#azure-deployment-template-name

Answer (score -1):

you set the name when you deploy a resource:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices",
"NAME": "MYRESOURCE",
  "location": "[LOCATION]",
  "tags": {
    "DeploymentLabel": "[variables('myVariable')]",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the name defined within the block (in your example, MYRESOURCE) is the value of deployment().name for that scope?

Comment: If so, we're already setting name. I updated the post to show it. The value is the resource's name. But after the deployment, I see a HASH + the resource name